# How to Investigate "Server locked (outgoing flood)" error?

Tags: linux, debugging, server, flooding

is there someone who could explain to me how to investigate "Server locked (outgoing flood)" error ?

Answer (score 0):

The must be massive outgoing traffic on your server. Any torrents or streams running on that machine?

Comment: Nope, not on that one :)

Comment: However I used allinurl/goaccess docker container on port 65535 and then I got that issue on that specific port

Comment: what do you think to implement that solution https://javapipe.com/iptables-ddos-protection ?

Comment: That ddos protection is against incoming traffic, isn´t it? I think your problem was the outgoing traffic...

Comment: Yes my prob is outgoing traffic however i d like your thoughts on incoming traffic to, if you don t mind